# Mount/download gdrive folder using Dockerfile

Tags: docker, mount, drive

I am trying to download a google drive folder using dockerfile. The docker is built for Ubuntu guest. What command in Dockerfile will help me do the same?

I have tried wget command. But seems like it works only for downloading files.